# Unable to read complete data using fread function

Tags: c, fread

I have an image file and I am trying to read 8 bytes of data from the 54th byte of the file and store it in a character array (of size 8 bytes). But upon executing it is only reading 8 bytes even though the pointer has moved 8 bytes ahead from its beginning position (from 54th byte to 62nd byte). When I am trying to print that 1 byte of data which has been successfully retained it is not printing anything.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fptr_stego;
    FILE *fptr_text;
    size_t f_size = 0;
    char str[8];

    // opening image file
    fptr_stego = fopen("stego.bmp", "r");
    if(fptr_stego == NULL)
    {   
        printf("FAILED to open stego file\n");
        return 0;
    }   

    // opening text file
    fptr_text = fopen("decode.txt", "w");
    if(fptr_text == NULL)
    {   
        printf("FAILED to open text file\n");
        return 0;
    }   

    printf("Successfully opened both files\n");

    // shifting pointer to 54th byte
    fseek(fptr_stego, 54, SEEK_SET);
    printf("File pointer location before reading %ld\n", ftell(fptr_stego));
    
    //read from stego image file
    f_size = fread(str, 8, sizeof(char), fptr_stego);
    if(f_size != 8)
    {   
        printf("Unable to fetch 8 bytes\n%ld bytes read at %ld position\n", f_size, ftell(fptr_stego));
        printf("Data retained: %c\n", str[0]);
        return 0;
    }


    // close files
    fclose(fptr_stego);
    fclose(fptr_text);

    printf("Data read successfull\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
Successfully opened both files 
File pointer location before reading 54
Unable to fetch 8 bytes1 bytes read at 62 position
Data retained:
```

This is the output I am getting upon execution. I have checked the image file data using `hd stage.bmp` command and it has all the data. I have done the encoding in the image file before and at that time it was working perfectly but now when I am trying to decode data from the file this is the issue I am encountering while reading the image file via fread function.

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but BMP is a binary file format, so you should use `rb` when opening the file; otherwise Windows will do linefeed normalization (LF -> CRLF) which messes with your bytes.

Comment: `fread(str, 8, sizeof(char), fptr_stego);` should be `fread(str, sizeof(char), 8, fptr_stego);` if you are interested in reading `8` bytes. If you leave it like you have it now, you should instead do `if(f_size != 1)` afterwards to verify that you read one element that was 8 bytes big.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing two parameters of `fread()`, the size of one element and the number of elements.

The synopsis of `fread()` is:

> size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

And `fread()` returns the number of elements it read.

Your call it this way:

`fread(str, 8, sizeof(char), fptr_stego);`

Clearly `8` is the requested size of an element, and `sizeof (char)` is the number of elements. Since the latter is always 1, the return value is 1, too.

Swap both values, and all is well:

`fread(str, sizeof(char), 8, fptr_stego);`